# Use SQL Server time datatype in C#.NET application?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server, time

How does one use the SQL `time` datatype introduced in SQL Server 2008 in C#.NET?

I've been trying to get it to work but no success.

Answer (score 69):

Here is an [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675168.aspx) that reviews all the new Date and Time datatypes introduced in SQL Server 2008 with respect to ADO.NET. As the document says: For `System.Data.DbType.Time` you would use the .NET Framework type `System.TimeSpan`

Answer (score 11):

I think you can use `TimeSpan` datatype for your purpose.
Here is an [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/usisvde/archive/2007/11/14/time-for-ado-net.aspx) that explains the use of `Time` datatype in ADO.NET.

Answer (score 5):

Also even people from Microsoft tend to recommend mapping the sql datatype time to System.Timestamp I would not recommend doing so,

since the range of sql time is 00:00:00.0000000 - 23:59:59.9999999

wheras the range of System.TimeSpan is 10675199.02:48:05.4775808 - 10675199.02:48:05.4775807

which is just slightly different and can lead to nasty runtime out of range errors.

Comment: What do you recommend?

Comment: Depends on what kind of surroundings you have, I typically tend to store seconds or even milliseconds if needed.

Answer (score 2):

you can read it using datareader using something similar to following statement .

```
TimeSpan time = dr.GetTimeSpan(dr.GetOrdinal(“Time7FieldName”));
```

Answer (score 1):

How are you accessing the data? Using Entity Frameworks, StoredProcedures etc.
If you have to pass a string representation of the date make sure that you do it in the format "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss" otherwise you will run the risk of the dd/mm/yyyy vs mm/dd/yyyy confusion.
If you are using Entity Framework or DataSets then you should just pass the parameter a DataTime instance eg DateTime.Now

Comment: I'm using castle active record to access data

Answer (score 0):

if your field is in time u can simply cast with (Timespan),

```
 while (reader.Read())
        {
             TimeSpan DBStartTime = (TimeSpan)reader["StartTime"];
             TimeSpan DBEndTime = (TimeSpan)reader["EndTime"];
            
        }
```