# How to deal with TIME datatype from SQL Server 2008 with NHibernate?

Tags: sql, nhibernate, sql-server-2008, fluent-nhibernate, time

I am using the `TIME` datatype from SQL Server 2008 and I am having some problems getting it to work with NHibernate.

```
public TimeTableEventMap()
{
    Id(x => x.Id)
    Map(x => x.Day).NvarcharWithMaxSize().Not.Nullable();
    Map(x => x.StartTime).Length(4).TimeDataType().Not.Nullable();
    Map(x => x.Endtime).Length(4).TimeDataType().Not.Nullable();
    References(x => x.TimeTable).Not.Nullable().Cascade.All();
    References(x => x.RequiredSettings).Not.Nullable().Cascade.All();
}

/// <summary>
///  MS Sql 2008 date type.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="map"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static PropertyPart TimeDataType(this PropertyPart map)
{
   return map.CustomSqlType("time");
}

public class TimeTableEvent
{
    public virtual int Id { get; private set; }
    public virtual DayOfWeek Day { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime Endtime { get; set; }
    public virtual TimeTable TimeTable { get; set; }
    public virtual RequiredSetting RequiredSettings { get; set; }
}
```

I get this error

> NHibernate.Exceptions.GenericADOException was caught
>   Message=could not execute query
>   [ SELECT TOP (@p0) this_.TimeTableEventId as TimeTabl1_15_1_,
>   this_.Day as Day15_1_, this_.StartTime as StartTime15_1_,
>   this_.Endtime as Endtime15_1_, this_.TimeTableId as TimeTabl5_15_1_,
>   this_.RequiredSettingsId as Required6_15_1_,
>   requiredse2_.RequiredSettingsId as Required1_10_0_,
>   requiredse2_.BackgroundColor as Backgrou2_10_0_, requiredse2_.Title as
>   Title10_0_ FROM TimeTableEvents this_ inner join RequiredSettings
>   requiredse2_ on
>   this_.RequiredSettingsId=requiredse2_.RequiredSettingsId WHERE
>   this_.TimeTableId in (@p1) ]
>   Positional parameters:  #0>14
>   [SQL: SELECT TOP (@p0) this_.TimeTableEventId as TimeTabl1_15_1_,
>   this_.Day as Day15_1_, this_.StartTime as StartTime15_1_,
>   this_.Endtime as Endtime15_1_, this_.TimeTableId as TimeTabl5_15_1_,
>   this_.RequiredSettingsId as Required6_15_1_,
>   requiredse2_.RequiredSettingsId as Required1_10_0_,
>   requiredse2_.BackgroundColor as Backgrou2_10_0_, requiredse2_.Title as
>   Title10_0_ FROM TimeTableEvents this_ inner join RequiredSettings
>   requiredse2_ on
>   this_.RequiredSettingsId=requiredse2_.RequiredSettingsId WHERE
>   this_.TimeTableId in (@p1)]
>   Source=NHibernate
>   SqlString=SELECT TOP (@p0) this_.TimeTableEventId as
>   TimeTabl1_15_1_, this_.Day as Day15_1_, this_.StartTime as
>   StartTime15_1_, this_.Endtime as Endtime15_1_, this_.TimeTableId as
>   TimeTabl5_15_1_, this_.RequiredSettingsId as Required6_15_1_,
>   requiredse2_.RequiredSettingsId as Required1_10_0_,
>   requiredse2_.BackgroundColor as Backgrou2_10_0_, requiredse2_.Title as
>   Title10_0_ FROM TimeTableEvents this_ inner join RequiredSettings
>   requiredse2_ on
>   this_.RequiredSettingsId=requiredse2_.RequiredSettingsId WHERE
>   this_.TimeTableId in (@p1)
>
> StackTrace:
>   at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoList(ISessionImplementor
>   session, QueryParameters queryParameters)
>   at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.ListIgnoreQueryCache(ISessionImplementor
>   session, QueryParameters queryParameters)
>   at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.List(ISessionImplementor
>   session, QueryParameters queryParameters, ISet`1 querySpaces, IType[]
>   resultTypes)
>
>   at NHibernate.Loader.Criteria.CriteriaLoader.List(ISessionImplementor
>   session)
>
>   at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.List(CriteriaImpl criteria,
>   IList results)
>
>   at NHibernate.Impl.CriteriaImpl.List(IList results)
>
>   at NHibernate.Impl.CriteriaImpl.List[T]()
>
>   at NHibernate.Criterion.QueryOver`1.ListU
>   at NHibernate.Criterion.QueryOver`1.NHibernate.IQueryOver.ListU
>   at TimeTableRepo.cs:line 47
>   at TimeTableService.cs:line 43
>   InnerException: System.FormatException
>   Message=Input string '16:00:00' was not in the correct
>   format.
>   Source=NHibernate
>   StackTrace:
>   at NHibernate.Type.DateTimeType.Get(IDataReader rs,
>   Int32 index)
>   at NHibernate.Type.NullableType.NullSafeGet(IDataReader rs, String name)
>   at NHibernate.Type.NullableType.NullSafeGet(IDataReader rs, String[]
>   names, ISessionImplementor session, Object owner)
>   at NHibernate.Type.AbstractType.Hydrate(IDataReader
>   rs, String[] names, ISessionImplementor session, Object owner)
>   at NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.Hydrate(IDataReader
>   rs, Object id, Object obj, ILoadable rootLoadable, String[][]
>   suffixedPropertyColumns, Boolean allProperties, ISessionImplementor
>   session)
>   at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.LoadFromResultSet(IDataReader rs, Int32 i,
>   Object obj, String instanceClass, EntityKey key, String rowIdAlias,
>   LockMode lockMode, ILoadable rootPersister, ISessionImplementor
>   session)
>   at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.InstanceNotYetLoaded(IDataReader dr, Int32 i,
>   ILoadable persister, EntityKey key, LockMode lockMode, String
>   rowIdAlias, EntityKey optionalObjectKey, Object optionalObject, IList
>   hydratedObjects, ISessionImplementor session)
>   at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.GetRow(IDataReader rs,
>   ILoadable[] persisters, EntityKey[] keys, Object optionalObject,
>   EntityKey optionalObjectKey, LockMode[] lockModes, IList
>   hydratedObjects, ISessionImplementor session)
>   at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.GetRowFromResultSet(IDataReader resultSet,
>   ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters,
>   LockMode[] lockModeArray, EntityKey optionalObjectKey, IList
>   hydratedObjects, EntityKey[] keys, Boolean returnProxies)
>   at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoQuery(ISessionImplementor session,
>   QueryParameters queryParameters, Boolean returnProxies)
>   at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(ISessionImplementor
>   session, QueryParameters queryParameters, Boolean returnProxies)
>   at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoList(ISessionImplementor
>   session, QueryParameters queryParameters)
>   InnerException: System.InvalidCastException
>   Message=Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.TimeSpan' to type 'System.IConvertible'.
>   Source=mscorlib

```
public List<TimeTableEvent> GetTimeTableEvents(Student student, List<int> timeTableIds)
{
    TimeTableEvent tAlias = null;

    List<TimeTableEvent> allEvents = session.QueryOver<TimeTableEvent>(() => tAlias)
        .Where(Restrictions.In(Projections.Property(() => tAlias.TimeTable.Id), timeTableIds))
        .Fetch(r => r.RequiredSettings).Eager
        .TransformUsing(Transformers.DistinctRootEntity)
        .Take(QueryLimits.TimeTableEvents)
        .List<TimeTableEvent>().ToList();

    return allEvents;
}
```

Comment: The `TIME` datatype has a parameter - how is it defined?

Comment: @JNK - I have in my ms sql 2008 database as a 4 so time(4).

Comment: on first googling http://stackoverflow.com/q/5301607/40822 it looks like you need to use System.TimeSpan on the .net side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Date/Time Support in NHibernate](http://jameskovacs.com/2011/01/26/datetime-support-in-nhibernate/)

Comment: Beautiful! This is exactly the information I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the TimeSpan type on the .NET side of things instead of DateTime (since there is no Date) like Dotjoe said in his comment.

Comment: Well from this chart is seems http://jameskovacs.com/2011/01/26/datetime-support-in-nhibernate/ it seems that datetime should work. I can't remember if I tried timespan(I think I would have). Anyways I am not working on that project at the moment. So it will be a while before I can test it.

Answer (score 1):

To put VahidN's answer explicitly, when you have an error message that says

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.TimeSpan' to type 'System.IConvertible'.
```

It means the property you're trying to map to should be a TimeSpan instead of a DateTime. Same deal with DateTimeOffset.

Answer (score 0):

A partial solution which I found useful is to use `formula=CONVERT(DateTime, <ColumnName>)` in the mapping.

The significant downside is that this is only useful for read-only access.