# System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime

I retrieve a table from the database that contains a column of type "time" in sql server, and I try to assign this to a DateTime variable but i get this error:
System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.

here's my c# code:

```
DateTime StartTime = (DateTime)dt.Rows[i]["startTime"];
```

knowing that the column "startTime" is of type "time" and I can change it in the database.
any help??

Comment: Check out [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5301607/how-to-use-sql-server-time-data-type-in-net-application).  Looks like you need to use a time span.

Comment: Devin is right. In .NET, SQL Server 2008 time types map to TimeSpan objects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
DateTime StartTime = Convert.ToDateTime(dt.Rows[i]["startTime"].ToString());
```

And if you know that it could be null..

```
DateTime StartTime = (dt.Rows[i]["startTime"] == DBNull.Value ? DateTime.MinValue : Convert.ToDateTime(dt.Rows[i]["startTime"].ToString()));
```

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to cast it as a `TimeSpan`:

```
var startTime = dt.Rows<TimeSpan>("startTime");
```