# Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net

Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
my type data column is time(7)

my code is

```
Protected Sub insertdata()
        Dim cls As New Class1

        cls.openconnections()
        Dim cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand
        cmd.Connection = cls.cn

        cmd.CommandText = "Insert Into Schedule (Room ,Hostel,Tanggal,Jam)"
        cmd.CommandText &= "Values (@room,@hostel,@tanggal,@jam:@menit:00)"

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hostel", listhotelx.SelectedValue)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@room", listroomx.SelectedValue)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tanggal", Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@jam", jam.SelectedValue)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@menit", menit.SelectedValue)

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cls.closeconnection()
    End Sub
```

Thank for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to *concatenate* the strings in time format `hh:mm:ss` and then assign to the parameter.

```
cmd.CommandText = "Insert Into Schedule (Room ,Hostel,Tanggal,Jam)
                      Values (@room,@hostel,@tanggal,@jam)"

str=String.format("{0}:{1}:00",jam.SelectedValue,menit.SelectedValue)
...
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@jam", str)
```

Answer (score 0):

Time sql-Type are mapped to TimeSpan Type in your code.
Convert your datetime to timespan, that is :

```
Calendar1.SelectedDate.TimeOfDay
```

For more info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131092.aspx

Similar answer: [how to use sql server time data type in .net application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5301607/how-to-use-sql-server-time-data-type-in-net-application)