# Problems with sending DateTime to SQL Table

Tags: c#, winforms, datetime

I'm writing WinForms code in C# and basically have the following:

```
DateTime localDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection("....[connection info]....");
Conn.Open();
SqlCommand sqlcomm = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO dbo.Call VALUES(...., @Time,...);", Conn);

sqlcomm.Parameters.Add("@Time", SqlDbType.DateTime);
sqlcomm.Parameters["@Time"].Value = localDate;

Int32 o = sqlcomm.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

This throws an error of "`When converting a string to DateTime, parse the string to take the date before putting each variable into the DateTime object.`" From what I gather, it thinks the `localDate` variable is a string but if I write to the console `localDate.GetType()` it says `System.DateTime`.

The column for "@Time" in the database is set up to DateTime, so that's not the issue. Any thoughts?

Comment: Where exactly is the exception being thrown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there. for Sql Server think among these lines

```
select cast(getdate() as time)
```

Problem is that in .net there is no such type as time, so you need to adapt

```
SqlCommand sqlcomm = new SqlCommand(
    "INSERT INTO dbo.Call VALUES(...., cast(@Time as time),...);", Conn);

sqlcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Time", localDate);
```

this is all you should need. Although, I think, you may not even need to add cast as DB engine itself will try cast it. The problem, I think, that you explicitly said your type `SqlDbType.DateTime`. But if you use `AddWithValue`, provider will do things for you.

since @Frédéric mentioned `TimeSpan`, you can try this as well

```
sqlcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Time", localDate.TimeOfDay);
' and no cast(@Time as time)
```

Comment: No time type in .net? Check [`TimeSpan`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5301807/1178314).

Comment: @Frédéric `TimeSpan` is not direct match to Sql Server `Time` because `timespan` can be negative and `time` can't.

Comment: See the link I have put in my first comment. `TimeSpan` is the official match for sql `time`, from [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675168.aspx#Anchor_2).

Comment: @Frédéric Ok. But you also should reed the note in there **Time values that are less than zero or greater than or equal to 24 hours will throw an ArgumentException.**. and you're right. `timespan` maps to `Time`. But it is not direct equivalent because it has much broader range than `time`. so, if timespan fits between 0 and 24 - it will work

Comment: FYI, you can simplify your `TimeSpan` version by just doing `localDate.TimeOfDay`, that does the same thing as `New TimeSpan(0, localDate.Hour, localDate.Minute, localDate.Second, localDate.Millisecond)` (and I deleted my old comments, you where right)

Comment: @T.S. Thanks! One question- now I've got it adding to the SQL database with no errors, but it's adding the date as 1900-01-01 20:39:04.793 which is....off :) What am I missing? `DateTime localDate = DateTime.UtcNow;` should tell it "now" correct?

Comment: @derekantrican There is one thing to keep in mind. how you store the date or time or date-time and how you view it.  First, check if your table data type is `time` indeed, because i feel - this is not. How do you get this result? What you see in your viewer is not what stored in DB. Date/time is a special data type and is not stored in any format. any viewer formats it for display

Comment: I'm using SQL Server Management Studio with an SQL Query of `SELECT * FROM dbo.Call` to see what is stored in the database. The "Time" column in my database is set to the type [datetime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx) . Does this mean I need to do `...SqlCommand(".... cast(@Time as datetime)...);", Conn);` ?

Comment: @derekantrican this is why you see `1900-01-01...`. You can store time in DateTime under certain conditions. But if you want to get time back, you need to do `Select cast(column as time) from ...` - you will see time now. so, really, you don't even care anymore about `cast` on insert. You can just do `sqlcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Time", localDate)`, this will be even better to have date and time. But on `Select`, get only time part. <-- All what I said is applicable when you have Datetime column to save time and time is within 24 hour span. This logic is not good to store time like 100h3m

Answer (score 0):

The UTC format is not an sql date time format whuch you specified in the parameters.add

In the past I have formatted the utc time to that of yyyy-MM-dd.

Comment: DateTime localDate = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.UtcNow);
 string testMe = localDate.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection("....[connection info]....");
Conn.Open();
SqlCommand sqlcomm = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO dbo.Call VALUES(...., @Time,...);", Conn);

sqlcomm.Parameters.Add("@Time", SqlDbType.DateTime);
sqlcomm.Parameters["@Time"].Value = localDate;

Int32 o = sqlcomm.ExecuteNonQuery();

Answer (score 0):

Given this table schema:

```
create table dbo.call_history
(
  id          int      not null identity(1,1) primary key clustered ,
  my_date     date         null ,
  my_time     time         null ,
  my_datetime datetime     null ,
)
```

This code works just fine:

```
using ( SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection( connectString ) )
using ( SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand() )
{

  cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
  cmd.CommandText = @"
    insert dbo.call_history ( my_date , my_time , my_datetime )
    values                  ( @pDate  , @pDate  , @pDate      )

    select scope_identity()
  ";

  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue( "@pDate" , DateTime.UtcNow );

  conn.Open();

  // double downcast required herebecause scope_identity()
  // returns numeric(38,0) which gets mapped to decimal
  int id = (int)(decimal) cmd.ExecuteScalar() ;

  conn.Close();

}
```

Comment: BTW `select scope_identity()` is old style. `output inserted` + `ExecuteReader` much more powerful